# MathJax is rendering SVG image twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, svg, mathjax, mathml

Mathjax is rendering the image twice.

We are using the following option for MathJax : **TeX-AMS-MML_SVG**

Following is the **MathML** **code** we're using:

Expand:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msup>
        <mfenced>
            <mrow>
                <mn>6</mn>
                <mi>x</mi>
                <mo> </mo>
                <mo>-</mo>
                <mo> </mo>
                <mfrac>
                    <mn>3</mn>
                    <mn>7</mn>
                </mfrac>
            </mrow>
        </mfenced>
        <mn>3</mn>
    </msup>
</math>
```

And MathJax renders it like this :

[image: Image of how mathjax is rendering]

Following is the MathJax Config:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
      MathML: {extensions: ["mml3.js"]},
      messageStyle: 'none',
      tex2jax: {preview: 'none'},
      showProcessingMessages: false,
      "HTML-CSS": {availableFonts: ["TeX"],font: "TeX", undefinedFamily:"'Arial Unicode MS',serif" },
      "SVG": {scale: 100,blacker: 1,useFontCache: true},
      styles: {
        ".MathJax span" : {
            "font-family": "inherit !important",
            "font-size": "16px",
            "color": "#4D4D4D"
        }
      },
      CommonHTML: {linebreaks: { width: "container" }},
      "HTML-CSS": {linebreaks: { width: "container" }}
    });
    MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("SVG Jax Ready",function () {
  var VARIANT = MathJax.OutputJax.SVG.FONTDATA.VARIANT;
  VARIANT["normal"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
  VARIANT["bold"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
  VARIANT["italic"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
  VARIANT["-tex-mathit"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
});
```

Comment: You might want to add a minimal example page that exhibits the problem. This renders fine for me.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger : I am unable to reproduce the error apart from my development environment. That's why I've added my MathJax config.

Comment: People won't be able to help if they cannot see what the issue is. If you cannot reproduce the issue yourself, nobody else will. The configuration works fine, e.g., http://jsbin.com/waxefebugo/1/edit?html,console,output, so the problem lies elsewhere.